# In Scheme, is there a built-in function called "ref"?

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

In Scheme, is there a built-in function called "ref"? I am reading "The Little Learner" and came across the following code:

```
(define line
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (θ)
      (+ (* (ref θ 0) x)
         (ref θ 1)))))

(display ((line 7.3) (list 1.0 0.0)))
```

It gives an error message "variable ref is not bound".

Could you please let me know what is wrong with the above code and how to represent the index of elements in an array?

Comment: No, it's not a standard function. Are you sure it's not defined earlier in the book?

Comment: It looks like `(ref list n)` returns the nth element of the list.

Comment: So `(ref θ 0)` is equivalent to `(car θ)` and `(ref θ 1)` is `(cadr θ)`

Comment: Are you using Racket or Scheme? Racket stopped being Scheme long ago; perhaps you are using one of the Racket Scheme #langs? If so, which one?  You suggest that `θ` in the posted code is an array, but the code suggests that it is a list. Arrays and lists are not the same thing.

Comment: Common Lisp has `aref` for _arrays_; Scheme has `list-ref` for lists.

Comment: If you follow the book "The Little Learner", you need to import the package `malt`

Comment: https://docs.racket-lang.org/malt/List_functions.html does suggest it's just another name for `list-ref`.

Comment: Also see the instructions at https://www.thelittlelearner.com/

Comment: @adabsurdum `nth` would be more appropriate to bring up for Common Lisp.

Comment: This is my first time using Stack Overflow, and I'm not sure how to reply individually. I apologize for any inconvenience caused.
1.In the preface of the book, "transcribing to Scheme," l_i corresponds to (ref l_i).
2.Using list-ref instead of ref has solved the problem.
3.I am using VSCode, and I downloaded Chez Scheme Version 9.5.4 from github.

Thank you once again to everyone who provided answers.

Comment: @clark I would highly suggest you to follow the book instruction. In particular, https://www.thelittlelearner.com/#TheCode suggests that you should use Racket, with the package `malt`.